# В течение vs. на протяжении

Tags: склонение, предлоги, окончания

При указании отрезков времени, во фразах вроде
*`в продолжение / на протяжении / в течение трёх лет`*,

- *`в течение`* заканчивается на *`-е`* (винительный падеж),
- а *`на протяжении`* на *`-и`* (предложный).

1. Есть тут какая-нибудь логика?
2. Есть ли другие, помимо *течения* слова, используемые в данном контексте в винительном падеже?

UPDATE: Меня правильно поправили: в моём вопросе *в течение*, *в продолжение* пишется с *-е* в конце. См. ответы.

Comment: Correct form would be *в продолжение трёх лет*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*В продолжение*, *в течение*, *в заключение*, *в завершение* are prepositions per se.

Historically, they developed from nouns in accusative using the same paradigm as phrases *в год его рождения*, *в минуту славы* etc., i. e. they answer the question *в какое время?*

*На протяжении* is a phrase (a preposition and a noun) which can be split:

> - Роль прямого советника при государе сохранялась, однако, на всем протяжении периода просвещенного абсолютизма (достаточно вспомнить роль Дидро и Вольтера). *[Виталий Куренной. Медиа: средства в поисках целей // «Отечественные записки», 2003]*

Answer (score 1):

Ну, во-первых, вы чуть-чуть заблуждаетесь. Правильная форма сложного предлога всегда  "в продолжение", и его не стоит путать с существительным. 
[Цитата](http://www.etoze.ru/pravopisanie/v-prodoljenii-ili-v-prodoljenie-pravopisanie/):

> Сложный предлог в продолжение, разумеется, также произошел от
>   предложно-падежной формы существительного продолжение. Но в роли
>   сложного предлога употребляется застывшая форма винительного падежа
>   этого существительного (кого? что?) — именно поэтому на конце его
>   пишется -е. Пример: в продолжение недели мне нездоровилось.

То есть -  всё то же самое, что и, например, с использованием словосочетание "в течение" в качестве предлога.

Что касается логики. Я (повторюсь в рамках данного стека) не так оптимистичен, как лингвист Зализняк с его верой в непоколебимые и чёткие законы развития языков. Но более чем вероятно, что это потому, что я знаю гораздо меньше уважаемого академика.

Но смею предполагать, что частично такому кавардаку причина лежит в орфографической реформе, упразднившей, в том числе, букву "ять" ). В дореволюционной орфографии - в дательном и предложном падежах единственного числа существительных писалось "ѣ": `о столѣ, въ/къ школѣ, о морѣ, о счастьѣ (а также о счастіи)`. При этом в именительном и винительном падежах писалось "е" `(гдѣ? — въ морѣ, но куда? — въ море)`.

Александр Исаевич Солженицын, будучи человеком с очень своеобразными взглядами на развитие русское языка (буквально никем не разделёнными), очень часто ошибался как в постановке своих лингвистических диагнозов, так и в предлагаемых методах лечения.

Но это не отменяет дельности данной цитаты:

> При нивелировке языка значительное разрушение потерпел предложный
>   падеж.  Уже упомянуто, как он пострадал от отмены "ятя". В том же
>   неосмысленном порыве всеобщего "упрощения" был срезан предложный падеж
>   ещё одного обширного класса существительных - среднего рода с
>   окончанием "ье", стали писать предложные в точности как именительный и
>   винительный: в Поволжье, в платье (без всякой логики сохранив
>   предложное "и" для случая полного окончания "ие": в платии).

И тут впору вспомнить об [ответе уважаемого permeakra](https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/903/242) )))

Comment: Before the reform, these prepositions were written *въ продолженiе, въ теченiе* etc., like nom. and acc. forms.

Comment: Upvoted your comment to fix it visibility, I've just meant that all these seeming inconsistencies are cause in some way with phonetic instability between vowels in triple e-и-ѣ somewhen earlier. I do not claim anything else, including alternative orthography )

Answer (score 0):

1) `В продолжение в трех лет` - 'в продолжение' - это предлог. 
2) `В продолжении банкета` - предлог + существительное.

Понять это нельзя. Это надо запомнить.